# Independent Sample Power Analysis With Unequal Means

Tags: variance, mean, statistical-power

I am running a test with two groups that have equal sample sizes (33 per group) but  very unequal means - **control group: 28,000** vs **test group: 80,000.**

I am trying to determine the required sample size for significance.  The Control group will receive no change while test group will receive treatment - the plan is to subtract baseline performance from testing period and use percent change for both groups to determine relative improvement of the intervention.  However, my confusion stems from the fact that the baseline difference is already so substantial that it almost guarantees a significant effect based on absolute change.

Is a power test suitable here to determine sample size or are the assumptions violated due to the large difference in means?

Comment: Because the control group differs from the treatment group in a material way, in what sense can you justify using the control group at all?  No amount of power will do you any good if the experiment is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Good question - the two groups are identical in regards to the population they were sampled from.  The only difference is the substantial difference in means...my plan here was to qualify impact of the treatment as a percent change from baseline between the two groups (e.g. difference in difference methodology).  My understanding is that this should be statistically sound as the two groups are identical other than their baseline.

Comment: Since they already exhibit a difference in means, you have two basic flaws: the first is that the groups *are* different and the second is that any difference in response you might measure could be attributed simply to the fact that one of them received *some kind* of intervention.  That would leave you unable to draw any conclusions about the efficacy of *this specific* intervention.

Comment: Ah, makes sense - thank you!  Not to go down the rabbit hole here but there is additional context warranted - the sample size (33) is number of observed days for the two groups and means represent the average occurrences per day per group.  The reason the test group is so much larger is due to there being substantially more individuals within it.  With that in mind, would you recommend that I switch to the average occurrence per day per person as opposed to testing the overall daily average?

Comment: Randomize them?

Comment: Aside from highly relevant comments above, any power computation would need to take account of population variances, which are not mentioned in the Q.